# how to add new language in django 3

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I want to add new language. it is  turkmen (tm) I spent a lot of time but I can't resolve it please help me to resolve it

```
PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
gettext = lambda s:s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', gettext('Russia')),
    ('tm', gettext('Turkmen')),
)
EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'tm': {
        'bidi': False,
        'code': 'tm',
        'name': 'Turkmen',
        'name_local': u"Turkmence",
    },
}
import django.conf.locale
from django.conf import global_settings
import django.conf.locale
LANG_INFO = dict(django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO, **EXTRA_LANG_INFO)
django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = LANG_INFO
global_settings.LANGUAGES = global_settings.LANGUAGES + [("tm", 'Turkmenche')]
```

Answer (score 0):

1.install gettext

> django-admin makemessages -l tm
>
> django-admin compilemessages

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).